# Typeset a page without a footer

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins

To typeset the copyright page of a book, I'm using `\vfill` to push the text all the way down, but I need the text to be aligned all the way down, where the footer usually is.

I'm using `scrbook` with `\areaset`. How can I make an exception to the bottom margin only for this page?

Comment: You could also use a TikZ `overlay` or `textpos` to place the copyright text there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\enlargethispage{\footskip}` to the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\vfill
\blindtext

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{\footskip}

\blindtext
\vfill
\blindtext

\end{document}
```